# Is there any alternative to Aviary SDK for image processing in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-imageview, android-image, image-editing

Please suggest Any open source alternative for Aviary. What are the hidden costs of using Aviary?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Vuforia](https://developer.vuforia.com/)
you may visit above link as per my knowldge vuforia is best one also it is an open source hope it will help you

Comment: I stand with @GopalSinghSirvi, vuforia is for image recognition not for image processing.

Comment: yes its ok. overall its an Augmented reality sdk. ImageRecognition is only a part of this sdk

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternatives that I'm going to test in the near future to replace Aviray that is integrated in our application:

1. Fotor SDK:

http://developers.fotor.com/features_android.html

2. img.ly SDK:

https://github.com/imgly/imgly-sdk-android-demo

Comment: But how we can get rid of "White Label", the branding logo of there?